# Force lessc to interpret @import literally

Tags: css, import, less, literals

I am dealing with a CSS stylesheet generated from source written in  [less](http://lesscss.org/) source code.  The source includes the line:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif');
```

lessc 1.1.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]

This is a perfectly fine bit of CSS.  However my version of `lessc` *(lessc 1.1.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript])* sees that the filename doesn't end in `.css` and tries to find a local `.less` file to include.   Resulting in the error

```
file 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' wasn't found.
```

Is there any way around this?  E.g. by forcing lessc to pass-through a section of text literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/417) on less.js Github

The solution seems to be:

add `&.css` before close url import

from

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
```

to

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&.css");
```

Let me know if it works, I remember opening a ticket months ago about the exact same issue but gave up.

Comment: It works. I even put my two bob in on the issue at github https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/417#issuecomment-3515649